# Measuring voltage in a 440 V motor start capacitor

Tags: capacitor

How can I measure the voltage in a stand alone motor start capacitor with ratings of 440 volts @ 60 uF avoiding destroying the DVM? We were given a formula for determining the power in a cap, but were not told how to measure the capacitor without changing the out the caps conditions or blowing up the multimeter?

Comment: What in the *world* sort of DMM are you trying to do this with? One of those Horror Fright ones?

Answer (score 3):

Motor start capacitors are only used on AC motors and there will be an AC voltage across it.

- To measure the voltage across the capacitor use a multimeter or voltmeter with a 1000 V safety rating.
- Switch the meter to the next AC range higher than 440 V.
- Connect the probes safely to the capacitor with the power switched off.
- Stand back, switch on, take the readings and switch off before disconnecting.

Do not try this with a $5 meter. Both meter and probes need to be adequately rated with a recognised safety mark.

Comment: No ac this is DC  and start caps exist out side of motors and ac circuits thanks though I have a friend who has a pile of DVM'S. From measuring caps .I just was trying to get a head of the problem .jim

Comment: What sort of 440 V DC motor uses a start capacitor? Please put all the information in the question.